# Highlighting whole word in HTML string using C# regexp

Tags: c#, html, regex

I wrote a method that highlights keywords in an HTML string. It returns the updated string and a list of the matched keywords.
I would like to match the word if it appears as a whole word or with dashes.
But in case it appears with dashes, the word including the dashes is highlighted and returned.

For example, if the word is `locks` and the HTML contains `He -locks- the door` then the dashes around the word are also highlighted:

```
He <span style=\"background-color:yellow\">-locks-</span> the door.
```

Instead of:

```
He -<span style=\"background-color:yellow\">locks</span>- the door.
```

In addition, the returned list contains `-locks-` instead of `locks`.

What can I do to get my expected result?

Here is my code:

```
private static List<string> FindKeywords(IEnumerable<string> words, bool bHighlight, ref string text)
{
    HashSet<String> matchingKeywords = new HashSet<string>(new CaseInsensitiveComparer());

    string allWords = "\\b(-)?(" + words.Aggregate((list, word) => list + "|" + word) + ")(-)?\\b";
    Regex regex = new Regex(allWords, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
    {
        matchingKeywords.Add(match.Value);
    }

    if (bHighlight)
    {
        text = regex.Replace(text, string.Format("<span style=\"background-color:yellow\">{0}</span>", "$0"));
    }

    return matchingKeywords.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use captured `.Groups[2].Value` instead of `Match.Value` because your regex has 3 capturing groups, and the *second one* contains the keyword that you highlight:

```
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
{
    matchingKeywords.Add(match.Groups[2].Value);
}

if (bHighlight)
{
    text = regex.Replace(text, string.Format("$1<span style=\"background-color:yellow\">{0}</span>$3", "$2"));
}
```

`match.Groups[2].Value` is used in the `foreach` and then `$2` is the backreference to the keyword captured in the `regex.Replace` replacement string. `$1` and `$3` are the optional hyphens around the highlighted word (captured with `(-)?`).

Comment: Thanks, it works! I was surprised to see that $2 captures the word also when it appears without hyphens.

Comment: Capturing groups are working like that, if you set it in a regex, it returns a group, whether empty or not.